# Wamp Server 3.0.8 right-click menu in the icon tray is different

Tags: php, contextmenu, wampserver

all!
So I have searched the web on how to upgrade the php version that Wamp server application is using and I found tutorials and so on. I have by default installed php 5.7.6 and php 7.0.6.

Now I want to change it simply by right-clicking the icon tray and selecting the php version as I saw on tutorials. However, what I found really weird and pissing me off is that the right-click context menu is different.

All the tutorials I've seen so far on youtube all have the same menu except in my case. Now the app is running ok.(php files are executing but on the older version of php which is 5.7.6).

The problem is I want to change the php version and I can't do it from the context menu in the icon tray.
Instead look at the picture to understand the difference.

[Click on this link to see the image of My right-click context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN5W1.jpg)

[Click on this link to see the image of: This is what it normally should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyxch.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The menu you are looking for is opened with a LEFT CLICK not a RIGHT CLICK over the wampmanager icon